# Cannot set 'timeout' value on Google Container Builder service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm setting up some container build triggers, which, by default, have a 10 minutes timeout configuration. As sometimes my builds are just a bit longer than 10 minutes, I'm trying to change the `timeout` value on the yaml file to no avail.

[Container builder documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds) says there's a `timeout` value with this characteristics:

> **timeout**
>   *string* (Duration format) [...] Default time is ten minutes. A duration in seconds with up to nine fractional digits, terminated by
>   's'. Example: "3.5s".

But I can't get it to work on the yaml definition file. Simplifying the yaml file I've tried:

```
steps:
- name: 'python:3-alpine'
  args: ['end']
  entrypoint: 'bin/notify.sh'
  env:
  - 'BRANCH=$BRANCH_NAME'
  - 'SHA=$COMMIT_SHA'
  id: 'notifyend'
timeout: '1200s'
```

And I get this error:

> error loading template: yaml: unmarshal errors:   line 9: cannot
>   unmarshal !!str `1200s` into duration.Duration

When I use `timeout: '1200'` I get:

> error loading template: yaml: unmarshal errors:   line 9: cannot
>   unmarshal !!str `1200` into duration.Duration

And when I use, just for trying something else, `timeout: duration.seconds(1200)` I get:

> error loading template: yaml: unmarshal errors:   line 9: cannot
>   unmarshal !!str `duratio...` into duration.Duration

Any clue on how should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This is a known issue, and we have a fix for it going out soon. I'll update this answer when it's out.</strike>

This is now fixed. Use `timeout: 1200s` to specify a timeout.

Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
steps:
- name: 'python:3-alpine'
  args: ['end']
  entrypoint: 'bin/notify.sh'
  env:
  - 'BRANCH=$BRANCH_NAME'
  - 'SHA=$COMMIT_SHA'
  id: 'notifyend'
timeout:
  seconds: 1200
```

Comment: I have tried that. It will raise an error `error loading template: invalid syntax`.

Comment: Previously this fixed the same issue for me but it seems they've updated it…. "timeout: '1200s'" works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue and the accepted answer didn't work.

I fixed it by configuring the project with the gloud command: `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1200`

Comment: That property controls the build timeout for GAE deployments (i.e., `gcloud app deploy`) and not GCB builds (`gcloud builds submit`).

Comment: It's confusing because both can use cloudbuild.yaml. For the case of `gcloud builds submit` there's `--timeout` parameter.